# How to access the isLoaded property of nativescript page component?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I don't want the `@loaded` event. I want the `isLoaded` property directly.

```
  <Page ref="page" actionBarHidden="true">
```

I've tried:

```
this.$refs.page.isLoaded
this.$refs.page._isLoaded
this.$refs.page.nativeView.isLoaded
this.$refs.page.nativeView._isLoaded
```

But all give me undefined.

Comment: And still, you should use the `loaded` event as it provides exactly the same functionality - you could raise your own flag that is being set to true when the event is triggered (in case you need this property to be reused outside the event callback)

Comment: `this.$refs.page.nativeView.isLoaded` should work, the value will be undefined until it's loaded the first time.

Comment: @NickIliev why should I use my own property if one already exists?

Comment: you will endup in creating an observer or timer to detect that property

Comment: @DickensAS I just want to do `if (this.$refs.page.nativeView.isLoaded) {...} else {do nothing}`

Comment: yes, the objective is clear, but the framework is not providing you such facility, therefore you a create a small timer/observer which will wait for that property in async mode, on the callback you detect the flag

Comment: @DickensAS AFAIK it does, with `this.$refs.page.nativeView.isLoaded` my problem was that I thought it would be false initially but it is undefined and then it becomes true.

Comment: Hi, @yukashimahuksay I am telling the same, you can observe `this.$refs.page.nativeView` and wait for that property itself will become injected from the framework

Comment: I have created a small demo https://jsfiddle.net/dickensas/o4kex7j1/3/